# Sequential numbering in the same image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, numbering

I'm trying to make a sequential numbering system where if I enter a number in one text layer, the other numbers will add by +1 date sequentially to all the other boxes. Am I able to do this in Photoshop, Indesign or in Illustrator?

[image: Sample calendar date]

Comment: Why is 6/9 following the 6/4? In any case this is possible in InDesign with the use of javascript.

Comment: @Lucian same applies to PS and Illustrator.

Comment: Sure it does, i just suggested ID since this seems to be a possibly text-heavy document, in which case ID could be best for its other formatting and page layout capabilities.

Comment: Ah sorry about the 6/9 following the 6/4, it's suppose to be 6/4 and then 6/5.

Also, where in InDesign can I make this sequential numbering system? What is the tool name for it?

Comment: Apparently there are already scripts made which you can use to generate a caledar - http://www.creativebloq.com/indesign/create-a-calendar-5132674

Answer (score 1):

Do it in Excel. Make a file that calculates your numbers and present the results as strings, if proper number format does not exist. Place the result into InDesign. There you can crop off the extras and add all decorations. You must change the starting day in the original excel spreadsheet. In Indesign you click Relink.

InDesign doesn't by default make a link to a placed spreadsheet file, but you can change that in the File Handling Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use InDesign to deal with this task. 
Looks like you can do it with Data Merge (check the extended [tutorial](https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-numbered-tickets-the-easy-way-in-indesign--vector-1863)), and steps would look something like this:

1. generate a simple text file, containing all numbers you want to have (seems like you want to have a calendar with dates). You can have an algorithm generate it for you.
2. create your design template in InDesign and use Data Merge to fill it in with the information @_@

While the tutorial is a bit long, it does help a lot, so - check it out :)